# Is session based authentication scalable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

I am creating a backend of my web application . But i am confused should i use JWT access and refresh token strategy or simply session Id based strategy .

In case of JWT , whenever user logs in in that case user will get access token and refresh token . I will store that refresh token in redis as value and user id as key . A lot of other setup i need to do here .

In case of sessions , when user logs in i will set a http only secure cookie containing session id on browser and store those session id's in redis for faster lookup .

But the thing is since i am a beginner , i would like to know if i go with session will it be scalable in future .
Are session based auth scalable . I am using express js and i will use express-session with redis for storing sessions . Also i think scalability also depends on architecture of backend rather than just on auth type .

Comment: This article can help you to stay away from JWT https://apibakery.com/blog/tech/no-jwt/